# Prove that any two maps $S^m \to S^n$, where $m < n$, are homotopic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Prove that any two maps $S^m \to S^n$, where $m < n$, are homotopic.

I've been fiddling around with trying to use the Simplicial Approximation theorem since that's the material we've recently covered in class but still can't seem to be able to tackle this one.

Comment: From the Simplicial Approximation theorem, you can show that any map is homotopic to a not-surjective map. If a map from $S^n \to S^m$ is not surjective, one can replace the domain of the map with $R^{m-1}$. The fact that $R^{m-1}$ is contractible completes the proof.

Comment: @SangjinLee I think you should expand that a tiny bit into an answer.

Comment: @SangjinLee You mean you can replace the codomain with $\mathbb{R}^{m-1}$...

Comment: @IBWiglin I mean Image of the map. This is an errata. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

Take cellular structures with each two cells (one point one cell of the dimension of the sphere, the points being chosen $x$ and the image of $x$ under the map of interest). Cellular approximation yields that any map $S^m \to S^n$ is homotopic to a map $f$ s.t. $f(S^m_i) \subset S^n_i$ (where $S^m_i$ denotes the $i$-skeleton), hence homotopic to a map $im(f)=f(S^m_m) \subset S^n_m = *$ i.e. the constant map.